# Values are not rendered using redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

before I write this, I tried everything to find a solution, but actually nothing worked. I have a standard react/redux app. (Both of the libs are at the latest version.)

Now I wanted to use redux-form to control my forms. I've added the redux-form reducer and copied the "Simple Form" into my app. I can see that on change redux actions are being fired, but the value of the input fields will never be rendered. 
Also the actions contains always just the last character that I typed.

I really would like to provide code, but for some reason, the code on your website seems to work. 
Is there some known reason that an input value is not rendered? I am sure the onChange action is being called.

Oh and I should mention that onBlur, the whole value get's deleted from the store.

EDIT:
I've removed all other reducer, middleware and stuff for testing. Still the same results

Comment: Can you share the relevant snippets of code?

Comment: You have mounted the reducer as `form`?

Comment: hey @Christian, did you find a fix for your problem? I'm facing a similar problem where I can't type anything on my input fields. onChange gets triggered but the input field doesn't update with the new value.

Comment: I did not find a solution after spending a whole day. Therefor I kicked the whole redux-form stuff and build the necessary parts by myself. Redux-Forms in my opinion has too many glitches to be used in a serious production app. Maybe sometime soon, I'll open source my own little solution. Much more lightweight than their stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I think I just found the solution to this problem and it's a little bit stupid =/

Here's what I had:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as forms } from 'redux-form';

import otherReducer from './otherReducer';

export default combineReducers({ otherReducer, forms });
```

Notice that I was importing redux-form reducer as `forms` and passing it as is to my combineReducers (like I did with `otherReducer`) using ES6 Object property value shorthand.

The problem is that the **key** used to pass **redux-form reducer** to our combineReducers **MUST** be named **form**, so we have to change it to:

```
export default combineReducers({ customer, form: forms });
```

or

```
import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form';
export default combineReducers({ otherReducer, form });
```

Hope this helps... I only wish their documentation were more clear about this.